# Apache TomCat working only on localhost - Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tomcat7

I have installed Apache Tomcat on windows server 2012 and can access it locally

So far I have tried the following:
- Opened port via firewall
- Opended port via my cloud server host.
- turned off windows firewall
- made changes to the server.xml file
- contacted my cloud server host who has confirmed that port 90 is working.
- my hosting provider have tried but they could not get it to work either.

I have stopped and restarted the service and none have worked:

Below is my server.xml file the logs dont seem to contain anything errors when I try to access.

```
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->


  
  -->

```
<!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
<!--
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->


<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
     address="0.0.0.0" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
    address="0.0.0.0" />
-->
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
-->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Any help please as I seem to be going round and round at the moment.

Thanks in advance John

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in linux. You can try this fix in windows to access tomcat remotely.

Open the following two XML files in text editor and comment out the below lines:

> 1) $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
>
> 2) $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

Comment Out:

```
<!--  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
      allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
```

Restart your tomcat server and see if this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of hours it appears my hosting company had not opened the correct firewall port e.g. they opened 80 instead of 8080.

Leasson learned always go with your gut feeeling. I asked them before placing on here if it was open but it was'nt.

Anyway anyone coming here relating to this please triple check your firewall ports are open.

Hope it helps someone else out.

Thanks
John